# how to receive the value of image in percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got 2 images and an input type number. Is it possible when on click the value of the input field and change to the percentage width of the image because now it only will take the pixels. In the example I scripted a simple 2 images and a input field.

```js
$("img").on('click', function() {
  var widthI = $(this).css("width").replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, ''); //become pixels need the value of the width i gave with it.
  console.log(widthI + " percentage");
  $("#widthI").val(widthI);

  console.log(widthI);
});
```

```css
#img1 {
  width: 12.5%
}

#img2 {
  width: 25%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/955031454781616129/JRpZOp1l_400x400.jpg" id="img1" />
<br>
<img src="https://gupta-strategists.nl/storage/images/team/_teamImage/JK_Gupta_Eigen_fotos_2000_011-2.jpg" id="img2" />
<br>
<input type="number" id="widthI" />
```

I've also made a [**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/flowwdelapro/pen/GwJzVY)

Comment: Percentage based of what? The wrapping container? The Screen? You can calculate it either way by imageWidthPixel / containerWidthPixel * 100, then you have the %

Comment: You can use the `naturalWidth` property to retrieve the original size of the image, before it was shrunk in your CSS. Then it's a basic percentage calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the images will be resized based on their parent sizes, you can do this:

```
$( "img" ).on('click', function() {
    var imgWidth = $(this).width();
    var parentWidth = $(this).parent().width();

    // Round values to get only two decimals (e.g. 12.3333339% will be rounded to 12.34%)
    var imageRatio = Math.round(imgWidth / parentWidth * 10000) / 100;

    console.log(imageRatio + "%");
});
```

Comment: thanks i was searching the whole web but i couldn't find any solution, this worked for me.